# how can i pass a NSString * param in a new thread withobject

Tags: objective-c

i would like to pass a (NSString *) in a new thread with object.
so that i can change it in background thread and in main thread i can get the change
the code like this

```
//this method will create a thread for sleepAndAssign ,and i want to pass the param type is NSString * .  the background thread is to change the param's value. 
 NSString *param = @"0";
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(sleepAndAssign:) withObject:param];
NSLog(@"param = %@", param);
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:4];
NSLog(@"param = %@", param);
...

- (void)sleepAndAssign:(NSString *)param {
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];
    NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:2];
    [NSThread sleepUntilDate:date];
    param = @"5";
    NSLog(@"backgroundthread param = %@", param);
}
```

the result output is

```
param = 0
backgroundthread param = 5
param = 0
```

so how can i receive the param change by the background thread do?
i know c# has **ref** keyword to do this.

in objective-c i know i can pass the address of pointer to method can solve this problem,but the thread pass the param need to be the **id** type ,i can't pass the param's address to the method. so how can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a different thread it won't work with `ref`.

The easiest solution is using a wrapper object:

```
@interface MyData : NSObject

@property (atomic, strong, readwrite) NSString *param;
@end

@implementation MyData
@end
```

...

```
MyData *data = [[MyData alloc] init];
data.param = @"0";
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(sleepAndAssign:) withObject:data];
NSLog(@"param = %@", data.param);
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:4];
NSLog(@"param = %@", data.param);
...

- (void)sleepAndAssign:(MyData *)data {
     [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];
     NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:2];
     [NSThread sleepUntilDate:date];
     data.param = @"5";
     NSLog(@"backgroundthread param = %@", data.param);
}
```

Note I say it's the easiest solution, it's far from the best solution. First of all, you should use a dispatch queue instead of starting new thread and instead of sharing data with the caller, you should pass it back using a callback block.

Comment: thank you,the easiest solution i got it . i just use this in some simple environment. so i dont want to create a wrapper object to solve the problem. so you have any other solution , that can use the fundamental type such as NSString  ,NSNumber  and so on ?

Comment: @lamb Don't use threads and selectors (methods), use queues and blocks.